# Using a combination of html and php in an echo in a php file (wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, echo

I'd be most grateful if someone could help me out here. I'd like to call a shortcode in a echo section, in a php file on my Wordpress site. I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

Here is the current code (working)

```
<?php
if ( is_home() or is_front_page()) {echo '<div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                <a href="http://www.ptmagazine.co.uk/testsite/"><img src="http://www.ptmagazine.co.uk/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/PT-Magazine-Web-Logo.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_2">
        <a href="http://www.focus-training.com/"><img src="http://www.ptmagazine.co.uk/testsite/wp-content/uploads/ads/header.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>' ; }
```

I'd like to replace the below bit with a shortcode

```
<a href="http://www.focus-training.com/"><img src="http://www.ptmagazine.co.uk/testsite/wp-content/uploads/ads/header.jpg" /></a>
```

I've tried the usual

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>
```

but I end up with nothing where the shortcode should appear

Also tried escaping the html with ' ' marks just before and after the shortcode call but the page then fails to load.

I've added the shortcode to a page here http://www.ptmagazine.co.uk/testsite/about-us/ (its the focus-training image at the top of the page, not the one in the header) and if I view source and copy the html for the shortcode and then put it in my php file all works well.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Not an answer but instead of using `or` on the first line you'll need to use this operator `||`. For example: `if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {`

Comment: What is your shortcode? I'm sure it's not `[shortcode]`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, the shortcode is [cm_ad_changer campaign_id="1"]

Answer (score 0):

This worked a treat

```
' . do_shortcode( '[cm_ad_changer campaign_id="1"]' ) . '
```